# How to avoid nested fold in when calling multiple Future with DartZ?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future, dartz

I have a piece of code that look like this:

```dart
final Either<Failure, Unit> resA = await deleteA();

resA.fold(
  (failure) => handleFailure(),
  (success) async {
    final Either<Failure, Unit> resB = await deleteB();
    resB.fold(
      (failure) => handleFailure(),
      (success) => handleSuccess(),
    );
  },
);
```

Basically, I want to call a first function, that returns either a Failure or a Unit (the success value doesn't matter).

Then, if the first function succeeded, I want to call another function, that also return either a Future or a Unit.

How could I do to avoid this ugly nested call of `fold` inside another `fold`?

I'm working with the package [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz), which is really cool, but lacks of documentation.

Comment: Hi @Manu did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(